# Better way to use if condition

Tags: perl, if-statement, coding-style

I need to run a test script which has over 10 conditions to verify. If any step fails, the program will fail and further steps won't be executed. Current, my program is like this:

```
boolean status = 0;

status = function1(param1, param2);
if (status) {
   status = function2(param1, param2);
   if(status) {
      status = function3(param1, param2);
      if(status) {
         status = function4(param1, param2);
      }
      :
      :
      :
   }
} 

return status;
```

I am not happy with so many embedded IF clauses. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What happened to all the sigils?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translated into Perl, you might write:

```
sub testing
{
    my $status;

    if (($status = function1($param1, %param2)) &&
        ($status = function2($param1, %param2)) &&
        ($status = function3($param1, %param2)) &&
        ($status = function4($param1, %param2)))
    {
        # ...do whatever...
    }

    return $status;
}
```

Or, given that `$status` is just a boolean:

```
sub testing
{
    return 0 if !function1($param1, %param2) ||
                !function2($param1, %param2) ||
                !function3($param1, %param2) ||
                !function4($param1, %param2);

    # ...do whatever...

    return 1;
}
```

Or:

```
sub testing
{
    return 0 unless function1($param1, %param2);
    return 0 unless function2($param1, %param2);
    return 0 unless function3($param1, %param2);
    return 0 unless function4($param1, %param2);
    # ...do whatever...
    return 1;
}
```

If you've really got 10 functions with identical calling signatures, then you might even do:

```
sub testing
{
    my @funcs = ( &function1, &function2, &function3, &function4, &function5,
                  &function6, &function7, &function8, &function9, &function10,
                );

    for my $funcref (@funcs)
    {
        return 0 unless &$funcref($param1, %param2);
    }

    # ...do whatever...

    return 1;
}
```

Notice that the first three alternatives will handle divergent function call signatures with just a messier layout of the code; the last pretty much requires the same function call signature on each of the functions in the list.

Comment: I don't like multiple assignments inside `if()`. Second example is ok, and perhaps `func() or die/return` is more common in perl

Comment: Fair enough.  Given the later versions, I don't like the first either; and give that in the question, the value is a boolean, you could avoid the assignments and simply test the function return values.

Answer (score 3):

```
return function1($param1, %param2) &&
       function2($param1, %param2) &&
       function3($param1, %param2) &&
       function4($param1, %param2);
```

This uses a [short-circuit](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And) to stop evaluation as soon as one of the functions returns a false value.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `&&` short-circuits, which means that in the following statement

```
func1 && func2
```

if `func1` evaluates to false, then `func2` is never evaluated because `&&` can never be true thereafter.

This means you can replicate your functionality without any `if` clauses:

```
return func1 && func2 && func3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to note one more option:

passed=true

passed=passed && cond1
passed=passed && cond2
...
if (passed) ...

Answer (score 0):

Another option that avoids all the nesting but that is similar to the original:

```
boolean status = 0;

status = function1(param1, param2);
if (status) {
    status = function2(param1, param2);
}
if (status) {
    status = function3(param1, param2);
}
if (status) {
    status = function4(param1, param2);
}
```

This style allows easy addition of more calls and easy re-ordering.

Comment: It will go through all the steps. Technically, not most efficient way.

Comment: @ericyoung You are right, but with modern computers worrying about optimisation of a few tests is probably a waster of people time. What is much more important is the ability to understand and to maintain the program. The original question asked for better ways to write the code and I believe that this, in some ways, is better.

Comment: @AdiranHHH You are right. It is much cleaner than other approaches. I wish I can choose more than one correct answer.